# Слетает позиционирование background при включении Yandex карт

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, яндекс-карты

Имеется сайт [scansorium.ru](http://scansorium.ru)

На заднем фоне наложена картинка

```
background: url('../img/bg2.jpg') center top no-repeat fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Все работает превосходно (можете убедиться сами)
, но на странице ["Контакты"](http://scansorium.ru/contacts) такое позиционирование перестает работать и картинка листается вместе с прокруткой.
Уже все голову себе из-мучал, не могу придумать что сделать с этим моментом.

Вопрос:  КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ТАК ЧТОБЫ ПОЗИЦИОНИРОВАНИЕ НЕ СЛЕТАЛО И КАРТИНКА НЕ ПРОКРУЧИВАЛАСЬ? (естественно не отказываясь от Яндекс.карт)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size:cover;
```

если не поможет почитай тут http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/l6BF3W0rymo. эта проблема только в хроме. в остальных браузерах все ок

Comment: Да, реально! Только в хроме. Проблема в том что вся компания, что сидит в интернете - сидит через Хром. Будут вопросы не по теме, но я надеюсь что Хром разрешил проблему

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в CSS следующее правило:

```
ymaps {
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```